# How to write the expression "img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]" in C++ OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to convert the OpenCV Python example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) to C++.
I'm stuck in this line:

```
img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]
```

where both `img` and `markers` are matrices.

What is the efficient way to write this in C++ OpenCV?

Comment: You linked the C++ example, not the Python. Anyways, the way it's written in the link *is* the efficient way to write that code in C++. While the python code `img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]` is more readable, it *has to* at the end of the day loop through the indices of `markers`, check what the value is, evaluate the conditional, and assign the value when that evaluation is `True`.

Comment: img.setTo(Scalar(255,0,0), markers==-1);

Comment: @Miki even though that is 100% correct I think it is not so efficient, as far as I know that will create a mask, then check each pixel f it is not 0 and then write to it. Probably the most efficient is to iterate through both of them.... However, I would probably go with your answer unless that I really need to squeeze every possible bit of performance

Comment: @api55 Unless measurements identify this operation as a bottleneck (which seems unlikely in that algorithm IMHO), then that would seem like a premature optimization. Both comparison and `setTo` are already optimized (vectorization + IPP support from what I can tell), so it's mostly about that intermediate mask. You'd have to use pointers to get ahead at least a little bit with a simple enough implementation. Some simple measurements show the original is around 3ms per 2^20 pixels, so question is whether shaving 1-2 ms off that is worth the trouble.

Comment: @DanMašek I totally agree with you. I think it is not worthy in most of the cases.

Comment: @api55 Since I didn't want to BS in the earlier comment, I wrote some code... and it felt like a waste not to write it up :D Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've already written some code to back my comments up, it would be a waste not to write it up.

NB: Testing it on an i7-4930k, with MSVC 2013, OpenCV 3.1, 64bit. Using a randomly generated input image and mask (~9% is set to -1).

---

As [Miki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008845/miki) stated, the simplest way to do this in C++ is to use:

- [`cv::MatExpr operator== (const cv::Mat& a, double s)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#a5516de530ce49cf1fdbfcedbc13fa64d) to create a mask
- which you the use in [`cv::Mat::setTo(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a0440e2a164c0b0d8462fb1e487be9876)

For example:

```
void set_where_markers_match(cv::Mat3b img
    , cv::Vec3b value
    , cv::Mat1i markers
    , int32_t target)
{
    img.setTo(value, markers == target);
}
```

Even though this creates an intermediate mask `Mat`, it's still efficient enough for vast majority of cases (roughly 2.9 ms per 2^20 pixels).

---

So what if you feel this is really not good enough and you want to have a shot at writing something faster?

Let's begin with something simple -- iterate rows and columns and use [`cv::Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f).

```
void set_where_markers_match(cv::Mat3b img
    , cv::Vec3b value
    , cv::Mat1i markers
    , int32_t target)
{
    CV_Assert(img.size == markers.size);

    for (int32_t r(0); r < img.rows; ++r) {
        for (int32_t c(0); c < img.cols; ++c) {
            if (markers.at<int32_t>(r, c) == target) {
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(r, c) = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A little better, ~2.4 ms per iteration.

---

Let's try using `Mat` [iterators](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aef8f88bc1f72757b0f2ddb3041611c73) instead.

```
void set_where_markers_match(cv::Mat3b img
    , cv::Vec3b value
    , cv::Mat1i markers
    , int32_t target)
{
    CV_Assert(img.size == markers.size);

    cv::Mat3b::iterator it_img(img.begin());
    cv::Mat1i::const_iterator it_mark(markers.begin());
    cv::Mat1i::const_iterator it_mark_end(markers.end());

    for (; it_mark != it_mark_end; ++it_mark, ++it_img) {
        if (*it_mark == target) {
            *it_img = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to help in my case, ~3.1 ms per iteration.

---

Time to drop the gloves -- let's use pointers to the pixel data. We've got to be careful and account for discontinuous `Mat`s (e.g. when you have ROI from a larger `Mat`) -- let's do processing row at a time.

```
void set_where_markers_match(cv::Mat3b img
    , cv::Vec3b value
    , cv::Mat1i markers
    , int32_t target)
{
    CV_Assert(img.size == markers.size);

    for (int32_t r(0); r < img.rows; ++r) {
        uint8_t* it_img(img.ptr<uint8_t>(r));
        int32_t const* it_mark(markers.ptr<int32_t>(r));
        int32_t const* it_mark_end(it_mark + markers.cols);

        for (; it_mark != it_mark_end; ++it_mark, it_img += 3) {
            if (*it_mark == target) {
                it_img[0] = value[0];
                it_img[1] = value[1];
                it_img[2] = value[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a step forward, ~1.9 ms per iteration.

---

The next easiest step with OpenCV could be parallelizing this -- we can take advantage of [`cv::parallel_for_`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html). Let's split the work by rows, so we can reuse the previous algorithm.

```
class ParallelSWMM : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    ParallelSWMM(cv::Mat3b& img
        , cv::Vec3b value
        , cv::Mat1i const& markers
        , int32_t target)
        : img_(img)
        , value_(value)
        , markers_(markers)
        , target_(target)
    {
        CV_Assert(img.size == markers.size);
    }

    virtual void operator()(cv::Range const& range) const
    {
        for (int32_t r(range.start); r < range.end; ++r) {
            uint8_t* it_img(img_.ptr<uint8_t>(r));
            int32_t const* it_mark(markers_.ptr<int32_t>(r));
            int32_t const* it_mark_end(it_mark + markers_.cols);

            for (; it_mark != it_mark_end; ++it_mark, it_img += 3) {
                if (*it_mark == target_) {
                    it_img[0] = value_[0];
                    it_img[1] = value_[1];
                    it_img[2] = value_[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ParallelSWMM& operator=(ParallelSWMM const&)
    {
        return *this;
    };

private:
    cv::Mat3b& img_;
    cv::Vec3b value_;
    cv::Mat1i const& markers_;
    int32_t target_;
};

void set_where_markers_match(cv::Mat3b img
    , cv::Vec3b value
    , cv::Mat1i markers
    , int32_t target)
{
    ParallelSWMM impl(img, value, markers, target);
    cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, img.rows), impl);
}
```

This one runs at 0.5 ms.

---

Let's take a step back -- the in my case the original approach runs single threaded. What if we parallelized that? We can just replace the `operator()` in the above code with the following:

```
    virtual void operator()(cv::Range const& range) const
    {
        img_.rowRange(range).setTo(value_, markers_.rowRange(range) == target_);
    }
```

That runs at around 0.9 ms.

---

That seems about it for the reasonable implementations. We could have a shot at vectorizing this, but this is far from trivial (pixels are 3 bytes, we have to deal with alignment, etc.) -- let's not go into that, although it could be a nice excercise for the curious reader. However, since we're around 10 clock cycles per pixel even for the worst approach, there's not much potential for improvement.

Make your pick. In general I'd go with the first approach, and worry about it only once measurements identify this particular operation as a bottleneck.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for taking it this far. One thing to consider, is the release, debug, optimization mode in the compiler. In a debug mode, the asserts in .at will give a huge overhead for example (however, we should always aim for performance in release mode). I would still go with the first option, or maybe the last one, since they are simple and easy to read with just a glance

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful